# Using unite and str_to_title: NAs united as strings and go undetected as NAs R

Tags: r, stringr

I have NAs in two columns that were united. Before uniting, I used str_to_title to create uniformity in the values.

The issue is that now the NAs are not registered as NAs and they've united as strings. I.E.

```
City         State        City, State
Denver        CO          Denver, CO
NA            NA          NA, NA
Los Angeles   CA          Los Angeles, CA
```

I tried hard coding it using `df[df$col == "NA, NA"] <- NA` and that didn't work.

Comment: When you have only a single NA in either of the columns, whhat would be expected output

Comment: I would actually rather it just be NA if either column is NA.

Comment: in that case, the `str_c` should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create an index and then update

```
library(stringr)
i1 <- !(is.na(df$City) & is.na(df$State))
df$City_State[i1] <- with(df[i1,], paste(City, State, sep=', '))
```

---

If we  use `str_c`, then it would return `NA` if there is any NA

```
with(df, str_c(City, State, sep=", "))
#[1] "Denver, CO"      NA                "Los Angeles, CA"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(City = c("Denver", NA, "Los Angeles"),
State = c("CO", 
NA, "CA")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyr::unite` with `na.rm = TRUE` to ignore `NA` values. while pasting.

```
tidyr::unite(df, CityState, City, State, na.rm = TRUE, remove = FALSE, sep = ",")

#       CityState        City State
#1      Denver,CO      Denver    CO
#2                       <NA>  <NA>
#3 Los Angeles,CA Los Angeles    CA
```

Make sure that `City` and `State` are of type characters and not factors when using `unite`.